# Unreal engine 4.22.0 download button isn`t working.Only clicking

Tags: unreal-engine4

I wanted to start learning using Unreal engine studing along with the course,but ironically hit the problem at the very begining.Hope you to help.

I created a new account at the oficial cite,donwloded the version for windows and let it `install in default mode`.First what I  hit was that after the download the Epic Game Launcher was not loading even after 10 minutes,but I let it go and just reopned,it worked(don't know if it can help you find the problem,but anyway).Then I did what every normal man would do in my situation:went to section `Unreal Engine->library->install engine->click again at the latest version 4.22.0 at the button download and...nothing.`Download button just let it be clicked to the heart's content,but still stubbornly didn't download anything or even started something.

Ok,I thought,let's do it old way:restart the launcher and try to do it again.Still deader than the dead.I went to the oficiall cite in the documentetion,but there I didn't find anything,internet didn't help either,but it hinted me that problem may lay in the antivirus,but mine is just a standart windows security(don't laugh),so I highly doubt that it is the problem.When I went to the launcher again,hoping that it may change it's decision and let me download,I found out that authorization stage was giving me an error called `S3`,which confused me even more.I have to say,that for some reason launcher required me to print my password again,although I`ve already hit 'remember me' button.So,I went to check this problem at the official cite,but under the name S3 I only found a problem when it appears in downloading game and at the description it said me to check my connection to the internet,what was even more confusing,considering that I was sitting there and listening music online.Thought it to be 1 time occurence,but no,it still gave an error.My years of expirience in computers led me to obvious solution:reinstall the laucnher and check what will happen next.It started working,but the initial problem of downloading the unreal engine wans't solved.

I know it'a long roller-coster like story,but I'd like to give as much information as I can,because I have no idea what can lead to such strange behavior of the launcher.Hope you to help me install the Unreal Engine.

Comment: Please try to make posts a bit more concise, 90% of this isn't relevant to your problem. Also, this is a programming site so it's not so likely anyone will be able to help in much of a meaningful way. All I can suggest is checking the downloads tab, it may be that disk space allocation is taking ages, or that you simply don't have enough space on your drive. Beyond that your best bet is probably to post your issue on the unreal forum.

Comment: @George ,Thanks,got it.But problem is I don't know what''s releant and what'`s not,so I can only study on my errors.Can you say which information is irrelevant?I'll try on unreal forum.And also,I assume it can be linked to the programming,no?

Comment: "And also,I assume it can be linked to the programming,no" No, not really, this is an I.T. problem. Only the fact that the download button appears to not do anything (along with steps on how to get to that button), and what you've already tried are relevant. I.e. reinstalling the launcher.